# "Compile" not in Scope dropdown list - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio in Project Structure under Dependencies I should be able to set the scope of each dependency. Most of them are set to "Compile", however I am unable to set new ones to Compile as it is simply not an option in the dropdown list:

[image: screenshot]

What should I do to fix this? Restarting doesn't help.

Android Studio version: 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Not sure why "Compile" is not in the dropdown list, but simply changing `implementation` to `compile` in my `build.gradle` under `dependencies` effectively fixes this.